# Node module doesn't work as intended with automator shell script

Tags: terminal, bash, automator

I am trying to start a [live-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/live-server) on demand in any folder temporarily with automator, and kill it when I'm done.

Live server is a node package. I've installed globally.
In terminal, if I go to any folder and run;
`live-server --port=XXXX`
starts the live server for that folder. But I couldn't manage to run with automator.

I've tried various things;

Automator > Quickaction

**Shell Script** This one doesn't return any error, but nothing seems to executed.

```
#!/bin/bash
~/.zprofile live-server --port=5010 --open=$1
osascript -e 'set alertResult to display alert "Live Server running on \n'$1'\n PID: '$$'" buttons {"STOP"} as warning
if button returned of result = "STOP" then
        do shell script "kill -9 '$$'
end if'
```

**AppleScript**, If I run it with out `watch` parameter it works, but it's watching `~/` folder, if I add `watch=` doesn't work at all (folder not found)

```
on run {input, parameters}
    set folderPath to (the POSIX path of input)
    tell application "Terminal"
        do script ("live-server --port=5010 --open=" & folderPath as string) & " --watch=" & folderPath as string
        activate
    end tell
    
    return input
end run
```

**Shell Script** So I've decided to make a bash script. Automator content;

```
source ~/.zprofile
~/.nvm/versions/node/v16.19.0/bin/launcher.sh $1
```

Here is the bash script content. This is working but this time live-server returns 404
(I believe it's about permissions this time)

```
#!/bin/zsh

source ~/.zprofile
cd ~/.nvm/versions/node/v16.19.0/lib/node_modules/live-server
~/.nvm/versions/node/v16.19.0/bin/node live-server.js --port=5010 --open=${1}/
```

Can someone explain what is going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the issue. It was a parameter issue.
In order to launch a WebServer with Services context menu;

Via `Shell Script`;

```
cd ~/.nvm/versions/node/v16.19.0/lib/node_modules/live-server
~/.nvm/versions/node/v16.19.0/bin/node live-server.js --port=5010 ${1}
```

Via `AppleScript`

```
on run {input, parameters}
    set folderPath to (the POSIX path of input)
    tell application "Terminal"
        do script ("live-server --port=5010 " & folderPath as string) & " --watch=" & folderPath as string
        activate
    end tell
    
    return input
end run
```

**Some Information**;
Although these 2 both valid codes they are working differently.
First one, works in the background creates a cog icon in menu bar while running, but If I click on close (cancel) icon it's still running. In order to stop I need to open a terminal window and execute something like `kill -9 $(lsof -ti:5010)` (not a good experience.)

Second one, opens a terminal window, which isn't pleasant, but If I kill it server stops.